# PInvokeStackImbalance was detected on WriteFile kernel32.dll

Tags: c#, pinvoke, kernel32, writefile

After i migrated from Framework 2 to framework 4, i get an error when i run the WriteFile function.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool WriteFile(SafeHandle hFile,
            byte[] lpBuffer, 
            uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, 
            out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten, 
           long lpOverlapped);
```

Solution:

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool WriteFile(SafeHandle hFile, 
            byte[] lpBuffer, 
            uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, 
            out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten, 
           **Int32** lpOverlapped);
```

The lpOverlapped parameter should be a int32, which is an unsigned long in
umanaged C++.

Original Error:

PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
Message: A call to PInvoke function '' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: David nailed it.  Your code failed because the default Platform Target setting in VS2010 changed from AnyCPU to x86, changing the pointer size from 8 bytes to 4 bytes.  Clearly you've never debugged this on a 32-bit version of Windows.  Failure on your customer's machine is not guaranteed, it tends to work by accident.  Using FileStream.Write() instead would be wise.

Answer (score 1):

`lpOverlapped` is a pointer and you should declare it as `IntPtr`, or as a `ref` parameter.

You are running a 32 bit process and were formerly passing a 64 bit integer, `long`, when a pointer was expected. The newer version of the .net runtime detects the error.

The solution is most definitely not to declare the parameter as `Int32`.  That will then be wrong if you ever compile to a 64 bit target.

Since you appear not to be using overlapped I/O I would just use `IntPtr` and pass `IntPtr.Zero`.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool WriteFile(
    IntPtr hFile,
    byte[] lpBuffer,
    uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, 
    out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
    IntPtr lpOverlapped
);
```

Comment: @Miguel Does this answer your question?